# Purpose of the icon in the root directory (default behaviour)?

Tags: android, android-layout

When we create a project, app's default icon is created inside `/drawable` directory, but it also creates an icon in the root directory, next to the Manifest file.

As I can recall, this did not happen like a year or more ago, and such behaviour started as of Android 4.0 or something.

What is the purpose of such icon? Why is it created? What service will use this root icon?

PS. I know that this is not crucial question, but I was just wondering why they started placing project icon in the root folder as well.

Comment: You mean the "Web Icon". It's for the Play Store only.

Comment: @BobMalooga Yes, has `web` word with it. Is this used by Android Studio during direct upload process? Cause I usually delete it, but I manually upload APKs.

Comment: As far as I know it's the one shown as your app icon in the Play Store, if found (you might notice it's as big as **512*512 px**). If not, I think It will attempt to get the icon from your app and try to scale it.

Comment: Hmm could be. Very odd indeed. Thanks.